# What is the Big-O worst case running time for constraint satisfaction problems in general?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, np-complete, constraint-satisfaction

Since intractable constraint satisfaction problems in general are considered NP-complete problems, what is the Big-O worst case running time of NP-complete constraint satisfaction problems?

Comment: The question is too broad.  Pick one constraint satisfaction problem.  k-SAT is a good choice since it has been [well studied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis).